# Delete or answer?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question, [How can thin wire in generator windings carry the high output current?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/31439/12772).  It turns out it is answered by a previous question on another site, so I want to close the loop and not leave it hanging unanswered.  It can't be closed as a cross-site duplicate.  I can either summarize and attribute the other answer or just delete the question.

I'm happy to do either.  I haven't spent much time on Engineering and don't really have a sense of how useful the thread will be here.  If it won't add value, I'll delete it.

I flagged it for advice, but it looks like the moderators here are stretched thin.  I'm open to an assessment from any site regulars so the mods don't need to deal with it.

Comment: You can post an answer, or post a link to the answer on the other site. Either way is fine. Having a question hanging around isn't a problem.

Comment: Answer (either a summary, your own answer, an interpretation of it, or anything that would constitute a valid answer normally really) with a link to the cross-site duplicate. Now, if anyone else asks the question here, your question can be used as a duplicate target pointing everybody in the right direction. You basically did this already, so all is fine again.